# In Fuse how can i migrate soap services into rest

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I need to use camel cxfrs for rest and i have soap wsdl and all code .
I need to use cxfrs and then add all business logic(as it was implemented in soap).

Answer (score 0):

The service impl is probably (hopefully) just Java logic that the REST service can re-use. The only things that change are the URL's to call the operations and the format of the data in the payload.

The SOAP services generally already have an interface or service impl w/ the SOAP annotations. All you need to do is add the JAX-RS annotations on top of them and boom! You'll have a REST service.

If you want to convert from XML to JSON based payloads.. CXF has some auto-JSON providers. However, at that point you'd probably want to break from the SOAP dependencies and might as well re-implement the models as Jackson-based objects.